# JPA - i18n - store all names in one table

Tags: java, jpa, internationalization

I have different entity types (e.g. Product, Category), all keyed with UUIDs. I would like to store their names in multiple languages. The following SQL table structure looks the most straight-forward to me:

Product(id)

Category(id)

I18n(entity_id, lan, name)

How can I implement such structure with JPA?

```
@Entity
class I18n {

    private UUID entity_id;

    @Column(length = 2)
    private String lan;

    private String name;

}

@Entity
class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    // TODO names from I18n

}

@Entity
class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    // TODO names from I18n
}
```

All solutions I can think of will generate different tables for each Entity's i18n data (@ElementCollection, @Embeddable).

To broaden my question: what is the recommended way to store multi-lingual data using JPA (or SQL in general)

Comment: You will probably never need all the name translations of a given entity. What you'll need is the translation for a given language. Finding this translation should be in your presentation layer, not in your persistence layer. Just don't store any name in your entities. Get the name, by language and ID, using a query. If you really want all the names in your entities, all you need however is a OneToMany association with the I18n entity.

Comment: Translations come from user input, I must store them somewhere (conveniently in the DB).

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But just because they're stored in the DB, in your I18n table, doesn't mean that the Category or Product JPA entity needs to have a field containing all the names for that entity.